# How to call jquery dialog box on button click and not on document.ready

Tags: jquery, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I don't know anything about jquery and I've just downloaded all the files for the jqueryUIdialog.

I am trying to work with it for a whole day now.

I have a form where the user captures some stuff and can also click on a button that opens another form.

I want to open the second form in the dialog box, and when the form is submitted, get back to the first form and continue capturing other details.

The problem is I've tried to transfer the data that was captured on the first form with: document.getElementById, but there is nothing there since the dialog box function is being called on document.ready, when nothing was captured yet.

Is there a way to load a page to the dialog on button or link click and not on document.ready?

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    var day = document.getElementById('day').value;

    var qry = '?day=' + day;

    .load('orderSandwich.php'+qry)
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Sandwitch Order',
                width: 700
            });

   $('#sandwich').click(function() {
       var day = document.getElementById('day').value;
       $dialog.dialog('open');
       // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
       return false;
   });
});
```

The day value is empty, because the user didn't get a chance to put anything before the document.ready is triggered.

The first form code:

```
<input type="text" name="day" id="day" />
<button id="sandwich">Sandwich</button>
```

Hope you can understand my question.

Thank you,

Sigal

Comment: Just...move the code into the `click` callback?

Comment: How? I've tried that:  $('#sandwich').click(function() {
  var day = document.getElementById('day').value;
  .load('orderSandwich.php'+qry)
  $dialog.dialog('open');
  // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
  return false;
But I get an error that .load is not a functions

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code. You should follow a few jquery tutorials to get your self familiar.

**First**

```
var day = document.getElementById('day').value;
```

This line should be in the click handler. You can remove it from here. Also, you can simply use

```
var day $('#day').val();//jquery way of doing it
```

**Then**

```
.load('orderSandwich.php'+qry)
```

You haven't actually attached this to a DOM element. Look at the API for the usage : http://api.jquery.com/load

**And**

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
```

I haven't actually tried it out, but I'm pretty sure that you have to attach it to a DOM element before you can use the DIV (JS people, correct me if I'm wrong). You're actually just creating a DIV element in memory. It's not attached to the DOM tree.

Another thing, you probably want to move `.load` inside some event handler as well. As I doubt you want to call the PHP page the moment the DOM is ready.

Comment: First - thanks for answering. I have copied the code from the site itself, and everything is working fine beside the fact that the page is opening on document.ready when no fields where selected yet by the user. So the $dialog = $('<div></div>') is fine. The document.getElement Is in the click handler, isn't it?

Comment: @Sigal I meant the initial call. You have an error in that code, I don't see how it can work at all. Is there a sample page we can look at?